# Registering a plugin to a library

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have 5 classes:

- GConfig
- GForest
- GTree
- GNode
- Plugin

That I would export as npm module (written in TS).

What I want to achieve is that GConfig will have a method `addPlugin(plugin: Plugin)` that takes as parameter an instance of a custom Plugin class.
The Plugin class would look something like:

[image]

The goal would be to have the ability to add multiple plugins, where each Plugin has the ability to extend the respective GForest, GTree and GNode of the core library (add to prototype) and have these augmented classes returned to the library consumer (client).
The possibility to add multiple plugins should exist, the order of adding them shouldn't matter. (Plugins offering functionality such as undo and advanced queries).

Do you think that this approach is viable and what is the common methodology to achieve this with Typescript?

Edit: I instinctively feel that this is a use-case for mixins, but I'm not sure about the setup to add these mixins dynamically in TS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's doable, but probably not with mixins because then you need to know in advance the members/methods that you want to have.

You can do something like this:

```
// myplugin.ts
import * from "mylib";

declare module "mylib" {
    interface GNode {
        myNewMethod(): void;
    }
}

class MyPlugin extends mylib.Plugin {
    plugNode(cls: { new(): myLib.GNode }) {
        cls.prototype.myNewMethod = function() {
            console.log("hey, I'm the new method");
        }
    }
}

mylib.GConfig.addPlugin(new MyPlugin());
```

Note that this is untested code and might contain some errors if you try it.

Comment: Thanks for the approach, I will try it out. One question though. Do you know how to patch the issue that arises when two plugins try to override the same method of the core library?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but if you import the two plugins from the same file I'm pretty sure that the compiler will complain, but I'm not sure. What you can do though is to change things a bit so that the plugin won't add things to the prototype itself but will return a map of methods to add, and the `GConfig` instance will add those methods to the prototype. That way it can check if a method name is already used.

Comment: Thanks again. Last question if you allow me. This means that combining the behaviour of multiple methods is not possible? Say, two plugins want to add to the behaviour of `tree.addNode();`, this means that it won't be possible to combine them? It sounds hard to accomplish overall, but the plugin system will be useless if that isn't possible.

Comment: It is possible, but harder to implement. Javascript doesn't support overloading, you can only have one property per name, so you'll need to manage that. For example: the Config will add it's own method with name `addNode` and will also keep an array of methods which had this name. Then it will execute all of them when the method is called. You'll need to manage that yourself.

Comment: It complicates things as I feared. But great, I'll look into that.